# Scrapy LinkExtractor ScraperApi integration

Tags: scrapy

I am trying to extract links from a webpage but I have to use proxy service. If I use proxy service links not extracting correctly. Extracted links missing `https://www.homeadvisor.com` part. Extracted links using api.scraperapi.com as domain without website domain. How can I fix this problem?

```py
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scraper_api import ScraperAPIClient


client = ScraperAPIClient("67e5e7755771b9abf8062e595dd5cc2a")


class Sip2Spider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'sip2'
    # allowed_domains = ['homeadvisor.com']
    # start_urls = ['https://www.homeadvisor.com/c.Additions-Remodeling.Atlanta.GA.-12001.html']

    start_urls =[client.scrapyGet(url = 'https://www.homeadvisor.com/c.Additions-Remodeling.Atlanta.GA.-12001.html')]


    rules= [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow="/rated"), callback="parse_page", follow=True)
    ]


    def parse_page(self, response):
        company_name = response.css("h1.\@w-full.\@text-3xl").css("::text").get().strip()

        yield {
            "company_name" : company_name
        }
```

```py
2022-10-24 18:13:49 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://api.scraperapi.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.homeadvisor.com%2Fc.Additions-Remodeling.Atlanta.GA.-12001.html&api_key=67e5e7755771b9abf8062e595dd5cc2a&scraper_sdk=python> (referer: None)

2022-10-24 18:13:50 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET https://api.scraperapi.com/rated.MarkAllenContracting.117262730.html> (referer: https://api.scraperapi.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.homeadvisor.com%2Fc.Additions-Remodeling.Atlanta.GA.-12001.html&api_key=67e5e7755771b9abf8062e595dd5cc2a&scraper_sdk=python)
2022-10-24 18:13:51 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET https://api.scraperapi.com/rated.FireSignDBAdditionsand.123758218.html> (referer: https://api.scraperapi.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.homeadvisor.com%2Fc.Additions-Remodeling.Atlanta.GA.-12001.html&api_key=67e5e7755771b9abf8062e595dd5cc2a&scraper_sdk=python)
2022-10-24 18:13:52 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET https://api.scraperapi.com/rated.DCEnclosuresInc.16852798.html> (referer: https://api.scraperapi.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.homeadvisor.com%2Fc.Additions-Remodeling.Atlanta.GA.-12001.html&api_key=67e5e7755771b9abf8062e595dd5cc2a&scraper_sdk=python)
2022-10-24 18:13:53 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET https://api.scraperapi.com/rated.G3BuildersLLC.71091804.html> (referer: https://api.scraperapi.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.homeadvisor.com%2Fc.Additions-Remodeling.Atlanta.GA.-12001.html&api_key=67e5e7755771b9abf8062e595dd5cc2a&scraper_sdk=python)
2022-10-24 18:13:54 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET https://api.scraperapi.com/rated.FletcherCooleyInc.43547458.html> (referer: https://api.scraperapi.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.homeadvisor.com%2Fc.Additions-Remodeling.Atlanta.GA.-12001.html&api_key=67e5e7755771b9abf8062e595dd5cc2a&scraper_sdk=python)
```

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: Yes, how can I fix this problem?  @Alexander

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like when using the ScraperAPIClient, it requires you to use that specific syntax `client.scrapyGet(url=...)` for each and ever request.  However since you are using the crawlspider with a linkextractor set to follow, scrapy automatically sends out requests in it's usual way, so those requests are getting blocked.  You might be better off extracting all of the links yourself, and then filtering the ones you want to follow.

For example:

```py
import scrapy
from scraper_api import ScraperAPIClient


client = ScraperAPIClient("67e5e7755771b9abf8062e595dd5cc2a")


class Sip2Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'sip2'
    domain = 'https://www.homeadvisor.com'
    start_urls =[client.scrapyGet(url = 'https://www.homeadvisor.com/c.Additions-Remodeling.Atlanta.GA.-12001.html')]


    def parse(self, response):
        print(response)
        links = [self.domain + i if not i.startswith('https://') else i for i in response.xpath("//a/@href").getall()]
        yield {"links" : list(set(links))}
```

This will yield:

```json
[
  {
    "links": [
      "https://www.homeadvisor.com/rated.TapConstructionLLC.42214874.html",
      "https://www.homeadvisor.com#quote=42214874",
      "https://www.homeadvisor.com/emc.Drywall-Plaster-directory.-12025.html",
      "https://www.linkedin.com/company/homeadvisor/",
      "https://www.homeadvisor.com/c.Additions-Remodeling.Philadelphia.PA.-12001.html",
      "https://www.homeadvisor.com/login",
      "https://www.homeadvisor.com/task.Major-Home-Repairs-General-Contractor.40062.html",
      "https://www.homeadvisor.com/near-me/home-addition-builders/",
      "https://www.homeadvisor.com/c.Additions-Remodeling.Lawrenceville.GA.-12001.html",
      "https://www.homeadvisor.com/near-me/carpentry-contractors/",
      "https://www.homeadvisor.com/emc.Roofing-directory.-12061.html",
      "https://www.homeadvisor.com/c.Doors.Atlanta.GA.-12024.html",
      "https://www.homeadvisor.com#quote=20057351",
      "https://www.homeadvisor.com/near-me/deck-companies/",
      "https://www.homeadvisor.com/tloc/Atlanta-GA/Bathroom-Remodel/",
      "https://www.homeadvisor.com/c.Additions-Remodeling.Knoxville.TN.-12001.html",
      "https://www.homeadvisor.com/xm/35317287/task-selection/-12001?postalCode=30301",
      "https://www.homeadvisor.com/category.Additions-Remodeling.12001.html",
      "https://www.homeadvisor.comtel:4042672949",
      "https://www.homeadvisor.com/rated.DCEnclosuresInc.16852798.html",
      "https://www.homeadvisor.com#quote=16721785",
      "https://www.homeadvisor.com/near-me/bathroom-remodeling/",
      "https://www.homeadvisor.com/near-me",
      "https://www.homeadvisor.com/emc.Heating-Furnace-Systems-directory.-12040.html",
      "https://pro.homeadvisor.com/r/?m=sp_pro_center&entry_point_id=33522463",
      "https://www.homeadvisor.com/r/hiring-a-home-architect/",
      "https://www.homeadvisor.com#quote=119074241",
      "https://www.homeadvisor.comtel:8669030759",
      "https://www.homeadvisor.com/rated.SilverOakRemodel.78475581.html#ratings-reviews",
      "https://www.homeadvisor.com/emc.Tree-Service-directory.-12074.html",
      "https://www.homeadvisor.com/task.Bathroom-Remodel.40129.html",
      "https://www.homeadvisor.com/rated.G3BuildersLLC.71091804.html",
      "https://www.homeadvisor.com/sp/horizon-remodeling-construction",
      "https://www.homeadvisor.com/near-me/fence-companies/",
      "https://www.homeadvisor.com/emc.Gutters-directory.-12038.html",
      "https://www.homeadvisor.com/c.GA.html#topcontractors",
      ...
      ...
      ...
    ]
  }
]
```

The actual output is almost 400 links...

Then you can use some kind of filtering to decide which links you want to follow and use the same api sdk syntax to follow them.  Applying some kind of filtering system will also cut down on the number of requests sent which will conserve api calls which will save you money as well.

For example:

```py
def parse(self, response):
        print(response)
        links = [self.domain + i if not i.startswith('https://') else i for i in response.xpath("//a/@href").getall()]
        yield {"links" : list(set(links))}
        # some filtering process
        for link in links:
            yield scrapy.Request(client.scrapyGet(url = link))
```

---

UPDATE:

Try this...

```py
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from urllib.parse import urlencode
APIKEY = "67e5e7755771b9abf8062e595dd5cc2a"  # <- your api key
APIDOMAIN = "http://api.scraperapi.com/"
DOMAIN = 'https://www.homeadvisor.com/'

def get_scraperapi_url(url):
    payload = {'api_key': APIKEY, 'url': url}
    proxy_url = 'http://api.scraperapi.com/?' + urlencode(payload)
    return proxy_url

def process_links(links):
    for link in links:
        i = link.url.index('rated')
        link.url = DOMAIN + link.url[i:]
        link.url = get_scraperapi_url(link.url)
    return links

class Sip2Spider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'sip2'
    domain = 'https://www.homeadvisor.com'
    start_urls =[get_scraperapi_url('https://www.homeadvisor.com/c.Additions-Remodeling.Atlanta.GA.-12001.html')]

    rules= [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow="/rated"), callback="parse_page", follow=True, process_links=process_links)
    ]

    def parse_page(self, response):
        company_name = response.xpath("//h1[contains(@class,'@w-full @text-3xl')]/text()").get()
        yield {
            "company_name" : company_name
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This works and we can add `if "/rated." in link:` for filtering links. But the website has pagination and in this case, we need to handle it manually. I already did it but I want to write the same code using linkextractor if possible because of auto following the next page. I checked scraperapi documentation and didn't find anything about linkextractor.

Comment: @skyriver  See the update I made to my answer....

Comment: Sorry, but it is not working correctly. The link is `http://api.scraperapi.com/?api_key=67e5e7755771b9abf8062e595dd5cc2a&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.scraperapi.com%2Frated.MarkAllenContracting.117262730.html` and I think it sould be like `http://api.scraperapi.com/?api_key=67e5e7755771b9abf8062e595dd5cc2a&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.homeadvisor.com%2Frated.MarkAllenContracting.117262730.html` @Alexander

Comment: I edited your code and now it looks working. @Alexander

Comment: @skyriver  See edits to the code... it will work now

Comment: yes we did the same thing. @Alexander